# overloading operator+ constructor issue

Tags: c++, oop, operators

I am learning C++ from a book and I find references and operator overloading really difficult. While studying operator overloading, I can't understand why this program won't work without a constructor that takes an integer as a parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class counter {
public:
    counter();
    counter(int value);
    ~counter();
    int getValue() const { return itsValue;  }
    int setValue(int value) { itsValue = value;  }
    counter operator+(const counter&);
private:
    int itsValue;
};
counter::counter() :
    itsValue(0)
{}
counter::counter(int value) :
    itsValue(value)
{}
counter counter::operator+(const counter& rhs) {
    return itsValue + rhs.getValue();
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I can't understand why the program won't work in the absence of these lines:

```
counter(int value);
```

AND

```
counter::counter(int value) :
        itsValue(value)
    {}
```

Comment: Why do you think the program won't work without those lines?  (You're right that it doesn't, but the question should show the full error message)

Comment: You're also missing the constructor definition

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have this constructor:

```
counter(int value);
```

then you can't do things like:

```
int n = 3;
counter c = counter{n};
counter c = counter{1};
counter c = 2;
// etc ...
```

The issue with your `operator+` is that you are doing exactly that when you convert the `int` value `itsValue + rhs.getValue()` to a `counter` which is the return type:

```
counter counter::operator+(const counter& rhs) {
  return itsValue + rhs.getValue();
}
```

Without the appropriate constructor, there is no way to construct a `counter` from an `int`, and you get an error.

---

You can choose not to provide an `int` constructor, by manually constructing a `counter` object, and returning that:

```
counter counter::operator+(const counter& rhs) const {
    counter c;
    c.itsValue = itsValue + rhs.getValue();
    return c;
}
```

Note that `operator+` should be `const`-qualified.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4dz8TT).

---

A few other fixes: `setValue` should return `void`. You haven't defined the destructor, but you have provided a declaration. Just remove the declaration, since the implicitly generated destructor is sufficient.

Comment: "This of course, requires a constructor for counter that takes an int" I think that what OP  actually does not understand, I would elaborate this "of course"

Comment: @Slava Hmm, not sure how much to edit, but I tried a bit. Is this better?

Comment: I mean OP probably does not understand/know that single argument ctor works for type conversion.

Comment: @Slava Edited. It should be more helpful now.